# Java - String conversion for DB Primary Key

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, hash, primary-key

I'd like to transform a String (from an XML file) to a DB Primary Key.

In particular, I would like to make sure that this value are unique, are all positive and respect the DB primary key specification that is: NUMBER(9).

The string that i try to transform have this characterization:

> PDR_20140909150001

Obviously i can ignore first part of the string (because are the same for all the file), but i have to transform an a timestamp string like `20140909150001` in an int value that must be have maximum 9 digit of lenght.

How can i do?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use **any** hash function as primary key because of **hash** function nature: it is surjective and can not be unique.

Comment: There are a lot of mechanisms for creating primary keys: part of them are implemented in db itself

Comment: I cannot touch db, i just can work in a software-side

Comment: @Andremoniy Is it Surjective or Subjective? I think you meant it to be Surjective

Comment: @Keerthivasan surjective is in fact correct, making that edit an ankward one

Comment: Sure, **surjective**. Stupid misprint. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In theory hashes are created to avoid collisions as much as possible but none of them are guaranteed to be unique. Much less so within the very strict requirements of 9 numbers. This is not going to work.

Either use a database sequence or a UUID.

Comment: Thank you! Have you got some idea that in software-side i can develop?

Comment: If you want a key generated by your software, use UUID.randomUUID() which generates a type 4 UUID. Other types are possible if necessary. Most optimal scenario (at least in some databases like oracle) is to store the UUID as a raw.

Comment: If you can not update the type from number(9) to raw/varchar nor can add a sequence generator to the database, you are essentially screwed. Generating unique numbers from software (I presume this is a clustered setup) is a hard problem

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot edit the database and the table on it. My problem is just, software-side, transform a string that contains this type of information: PDR_dateandhour, in a primary key.

Comment: I can understand why data type changes might be hard, but adding a sequence to a database is not allowed? Tell your boss it's by **far** the best solution. Anything else will take a lot of time to develop and will be prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

I would call your "hash code" a *transformation* rather.

In general you can't make such transformation because if the `String` is *long* enough (e.g. longer than 10 characters), there are more possible values in that string than a number with 9 digits can represent.

**IF** the input string is guaranteed to be shorter than a limit, you can make such transformation. The max input limit is 2 characters because 1 character in Java is 16 bits which is 2 bytes, 3 characters would be 6 bytes (which doesn't fit into `NUMBER(9)`). Max value of `NUMBER(9)` is `999999999` which is `0x3B9AC9FF` which is 4 bytes.

Conversion:

```
String key = ...; // Read key, must be 2 characters at the most

int dbKey = 0; // NUMBER(9) fits into a Java int
for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
    dbKey <<= 16;
    dbKey += key.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: you're right! but maybe is better if i open a question more specifical.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a bijective Integer to String function, that is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833075/bijective-integer-string-function).

Comment: Just a note that it does not have to be bijective, injective would be enough (in theory that is, a bijective function can be more memory-efficient, but is not needed)